# .jar file won't run on some computers

Tags: java, macos

[image: The error in question]

So I've been trying to send my java app to my friends for them to test it. However, the .jar file will only open on my fellow CS student friends' computers because they already have a JDK installed. I try to walk my other friends through a Java install through this link:

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

However, whenever they try to open the app it spits this error (it's not a security and privacy issue, that one gets resolved before this one hits). Am I teaching the install wrong? I don't know what's happening.

Also, the app was written in JDK-13, and all my friends' versions are 13/14.

Thanks for any ideas.

EDIT: There is no console, so no I cannot get the error message. Sorry about that.

Comment: Have you tried setting path to 'JAVA HOME'?

Comment: @JayantJeetTomar No I haven't, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @JayantJeetTomar I'm seeing a lot of stuff about Windows, this is only occurring on Macs. Would the path still be an issue?

Comment: yes. See my answer. Try adding path and running jar file again

Comment: Open a console and run the program through there (with java -jar <your-jar-name>.jar). That way you will get the error message.

Comment: @Taschi ```Error: Unable to access jarfile ACCT_2.jar```, not very useful info but it might help.

Comment: @jackwilmer navigate to the folder where your jar file is located before running that command

Comment: @jackwilmer You need to actually be in the same directory where the JAR file lies, otherwise that command won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem occurs because 'JAVA_HOME' path is not set.

Go through this [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) for steps to set 'JAVA_HOME' path and try running your .jar file again.

Alternatively, you could have also packaged the project as an installation setup. That'd look more professional. You can try [InnoSetup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) for this.